# Time complexity of the expression

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

I am trying to find the time complexity of the following:

```
Algorithm C solves X by dividing a problem of size n into 2 subproblems of size n/2, recursively solving each sub problem, and then combining the solutions in O(n^3) time.
```

My try:

```
2 T(n/2) + O(n^3)
```

Can I write directly that the time complexity will be : O(n^3)

Comment: It would be good if, questions are more elaborated and added with code snippets. However yeah time complexity in the above scenario is O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

using master theorem we can solve `2 T(n/2)` which would result in O(n) then as per the question add O(n^3)

thus.,
`O(n) + O(n^3)`

As you have mentioned The time complexity will be : **O(n^3)** but be sure to solve the `2 T(n/2)' since if this part has a greater complexity it would affect the final result.